# KafkaConnect Rest API Basic Authentication Issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are currently using Kafka version 2.11 and KafakConnect 2.0.0 which is part of the hortonworks distribution we have got. We have enabled Rest API basic authentication by adding this in connect.distributed.properties

```
listeners=https://${hostname}:${restPort}
```

and following all the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/basic-auth.html).

Now everything is working and we are able to use basic auth in all GET and POST operations on the leader node while only GET operations are working on the worker nodes. When we try to do POST operation on worker node we get this Error -

`{"error_code":500,"message":"IO Error trying to forward REST request: org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpResponseException: HTTP protocol violation: Authentication challenge without WWW-Authenticate header"}`

As per message its quite evident that the worker is trying to forward the POST/DELETE request to Leader and its failing to do so. A sample DELETE request which is failing is like this:

`curl -X DELETE -i -H 'Accept:application/json' -H 'Authorization:Basic base64encodedpassword' https://hostname:18084/connectors/someconnector`

Please help if someone has faced this issue before. May be something is wrong in formation of my rest request but it works fine when executed on cluster leader... Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Are you having troubles with `POST` or `DELETE` ?

Comment: Sorry.. i pasted a delete example but I get same error in Post and Delete both. While Get operations like checking status of connectors and tasks work fine on all nodes.

Comment: what does the listener line do? I didn't know it was needed to make authentication work.

Comment: It was mainly to listen on https rather than http, nothing to do with basic auth anyway. Its an old thread, so I couldn't recall if we solved it or how we solved it. Will check and update this post.